# Someone with a Durometer please advise me regarding Shore A values?

Tags: silicone

I need to buy some silicone around 30 - 40 Shore A units of rubber softness.

It's for vibration dampers in a home engineering project.

Online it only says that an average school rubber is 40A, Except rubbers vary a lot in springiness, a professional rubber is soft, about twice as soft as a rubber from a souvenir shop.

Can someone with lots of rubbers at their house tell me what the values are for different rubbers?

Even better, can you *www.youtube.com/upload* record a durometer tests of various rubbers and then squeeze them and bend them so that i can see how soft they are relative to the fingers? I don't know how to find help on this topic.

A video to illustrate Shore A values would help many people in future.

Thank You

Comment: Have found: human thumb is 25A, a Staedtler white rubber eraser 55A

Comment: found some info here: http://www.paramountind.com/pdfs/paramount_durometer_scale_guide.pdf  ... bathroom caulk is 30, soft art rubber is 30. red pencil rubber is 40.